# Is it ok to write I am availabl upto 12AM night as per US time

Tags: time-zones

I am from India. I want to reply one mail to US people by saying that I will be available upto 12AM night as per US time.

India Standard Time Night 12AM I am available. How can I convey same message to US person?

Comment: Provide them an easy way to compare the time zones, e.g. [Mumbai (your time) vs Los Angeles](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingtime.html?day=11&month=4&year=2020&p1=44&p2=137&iv=0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to user experience. This is more a question for https://english.stackexchange.com/ IMO.

Comment: [ELU mod here] No, this is off-topic on English. We don't do proof-reading. This is a question about how to write about timezones in a UX context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build my answer to make it the easiest for the recipient. Use their timezone, don't let them do the math to calculate the timezone your available.

Find the State location of your person and check timezone there.

The answer can be:

> I'm available until 12AM [Insert their timezone here]

Keep in mind, in United States you can have 6 timezones:

1. Hawaii timezone
2. Alaska timezone
3. Pacific timezone
4. Mountain timezone
5. Central timezone
6. Eastern timezone

Full article here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_States

[image]